# xlookup with multiply separate match criteria

Tags: excel-formula, office365, match, partial, approximate

I've got 2 tables with same criteria "Num"

I'm using this formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(NUM=RANGE_NUM)*(DATE=RANGE_DATE),GOAL_ARRAY,,,)**
```

It's working only for exact match, but I want fill up all rows with goal column result

Current result in table 1

TABLE 1 (several dates with 1-2 days deviance)

| Num | Date | Goal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1136 | 2022-01-01 | 250 |
| 1136 | 2022-01-02 | =N/A |
| 1136 | 2022-01-03 | =N/A |
| 1136 | 2022-02-01 | 500 |
| 1136 | 2022-02-02 | =N/A |
| 1136 | 2022-02-03 | =N/A |
| 1136 | 2022-03-01 | 250 |
| 1136 | 2022-03-02 | =N/A |
| 1136 | 2022-03-03 | =N/A |

TABLE 2 (exact date)

| Num | Date | Goal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1136 | 2022-01-01 | 250 |
| 1136 | 2022-02-01 | 500 |
| 1136 | 2022-03-01 | 250 |

Is it possible to make "NUM" exact match with "DATE" approximate?

TABLE 3 (expected result)

| Num | Date | Goal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1136 | 2022-01-01 | 250 |
| 1136 | 2022-01-02 | 250 |
| 1136 | 2022-01-03 | 250 |
| 1136 | 2022-02-01 | 500 |
| 1136 | 2022-02-02 | 500 |
| 1136 | 2022-02-03 | 500 |
| 1136 | 2022-03-01 | 250 |
| 1136 | 2022-03-02 | 250 |
| 1136 | 2022-03-03 | 250 |

Maybe I have to use other formula combinations? Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FILTER():

```
=XLOOKUP(B2,FILTER($F$2:$F$5,$E$2:$E$5=A2),FILTER($G$2:$G$5,$E$2:$E$5=A2),"",-1)
```

[image]